# iPhone simulator minimizes the application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm debugging my app with the simulator. And for some moment in concrete situation the app gets mimimized. I think there is some problem in my code (Most likely some variable is not initialized, because sometimes everything works) . But how can I catch this moment.

In xcode is still written that the program is running and I can put breakpoints and the will trigger.

And if i will reopen my application it will continue working... 
When using device the are no problems too...

How can i catch this moment and pause the program to view a callstack.

**EDIT**

I Think the problem is here:
[Objective-c singleton object does not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054247/objective-c-singleton-object-does-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: To be clear, you think your app is being put in the background randomly?

Comment: @raidfive: No, it happens in a concrete situation sometimes. But it is hard to provide the code because it's big. The question is how can i stop the program when it's being minimized - so i can view a callstack

Comment: If it doesn't happen when debugging on the device, why not just leave it?

Comment: @Aurum: because a good program should work in every situation

Comment: I've never heard of this happening personally. I wasn't aware it was possible to background an app programmatically without user interaction.

Comment: @raidfive: maybe it's because i'm using virtual machine, not a mac

Comment: @Andrew I think you're asking for trouble with that kind of setup. Good luck solving the issue, though I still don't get why you want to use the sim so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try catching it in the `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`-methode in the app delegate, at least then you will see specifically when it happens.

Comment: Thanks, i've already done it. I've found some problem and now trying to understand where does it come from

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem ? My app is minimizing by its own  and dont know what is the issue... iphone4s .. OS 7.0.4