# Objective-c singleton object does not working as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have a problem. There is class to store game progress:

```
struct GameData {
    PackData & packDataById(LEVEL_PACK packId);
    int gameVersion;
    AudioData audio;
    PackData sunrise;
    PackData monochrome;
    PackData nature;
};

//singleton
@interface GameDataObject : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
    GameData data_;
}
+(GameDataObject*) sharedObject;
-(id) initForFirstLaunch;
-(GameData*) data;
-(void) save;
@end
```

and implementation:

```
@implementation GameDataObject

static GameDataObject *_sharedDataObject = nil;

+ (GameDataObject*) sharedObject
{
    if (!_sharedDataObject) {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSData *encodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:Key];
        if (!encodedObject)  {
            _sharedDataObject = [[GameDataObject alloc] initForFirstLaunch];
        }
        else {
            _sharedDataObject = (GameDataObject*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: encodedObject];
        }
    }
    return _sharedDataObject;
}

-(GameData*) data
{
    return &data_;
}

-(id) initForFirstLaunch
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        data_.audio.reset();
        data_.sunrise.reset();
        data_.monochrome.reset();
        data_.nature.reset();
        data_.gameVersion = 1;
        data_.sunrise.levelData[0].state = LEVEL_OPENED;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) save
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self] forKey:Key];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeInt:data_.gameVersion forKey:@"game-version"];
    [encoder encodeBytes:(uint8_t*)&data_.audio length:sizeof(AudioData) forKey:@"audio-data"];
    [encoder encodeBytes:(uint8_t*)&data_.sunrise length:sizeof(PackData) forKey:@"sunrise-pack"];
    [encoder encodeBytes:(uint8_t*)&data_.monochrome length:sizeof(PackData) forKey:@"monochrome-pack"];
    [encoder encodeBytes:(uint8_t*)&data_.nature length:sizeof(PackData) forKey:@"nature-pack"];
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        data_.gameVersion = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"game-version"];
        NSUInteger length = 0;
        {
            const uint8_t *buffer = [decoder decodeBytesForKey:@"audio-data" returnedLength:&length];
            assert(length);
            memcpy(&data_.audio, buffer, length);
        }

        {
            const uint8_t *buffer = [decoder decodeBytesForKey:@"sunrise-pack" returnedLength:&length];
            assert(length);
            memcpy(&data_.sunrise, buffer, length);
        }

        {
            const uint8_t *buffer = [decoder decodeBytesForKey:@"monochrome-pack" returnedLength:&length];
            assert(length);
            memcpy(&data_.monochrome, buffer, length);
        }

        {
            const uint8_t *buffer = [decoder decodeBytesForKey:@"nature-pack" returnedLength:&length];
            assert(length);
            memcpy(&data_.nature, buffer, length);      
        }
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

It loads and saves itself correctly when save is called directly after initialization and nothing more is done.

But when I try a simple thing. I write in `appDidFinishLaunching`

```
GameDataObject *obj = [GameDataObject sharedObject];
```

Then everything is done - just one simple menu is loaded, and I minimize the application so

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
    [[GameDataObject sharedObject] save];
}
```

is executed. And in this method `obj` is totally corrupted (before saving), sometimes it's even seen with debugger as another class object.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Just launching the app and minimizing it causes the same problem.

Comment: In `+sharedObject`, you're not retaining the `_sharedDataObject` when it's unarchived using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. It might be causing your trouble.

Comment: @JoostK: You are totally right! I'm feeling myself so stupid. Please add this as an answer so i could close this theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comment, you have a memory bug when unarchiving the data using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

The method `+[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:]` returns an autoreleased object (you can tell from the naming convention: it doesn't contain either `new`, `alloc` or `copy`) so you'd have to take ownership of the object by sending it a `retain` message. Now the object won't be released by the autorelease pool at the end of the runloop.

Answer (score 2):

While you have an answer, your overall app architecture could use a bit of refinement.

Notably, it is generally quite fragile to have some massive amount of persistent logic associated with an arbitrary singleton's instantiation.   It introduces all kinds of weird ordering dependencies or other mechanisms via which a seemingly minor change can cause your code to break.

A far less fragile pattern is to associate reconstruction of state with known points in an application's lifespan.   I.e. if the state is required for the app to work, load the state in `applcationDidFinishLaunching:`.  If the state is only required by a subsystem, load it when the subsystem is loaded.

Doing so reduces complexity and, by implication, reduces the maintenance costs of your code.  Any indeterminism you can eliminate is a future bug removed.

Comment: GameData is a structure to keep progress and settings. It's used from the first menu and used through all the game (in pack select scene, in level select scene, in level win scene). Also it's called in the code in applicationDidFinishLaunching just to find a bug. Actually it will be called at first need

Comment: I would suggest unarchiving at quite explicitly at `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` and persisting it periodically as appropriate.   *Magic* through seemingly innocuous methods will often bite you down the road.

Answer (score 1):

When reading an archived shared object, you must retain it when assigning to your singleton variable. NSCoder methods for unarchiving always return autoreleased objects.